# Merging specific rows in R where there is a NA value in one

Tags: r

I have data that is merged down but on every hour mark, there is a row in my data with an elevation value and a row in my data with a NA. I want to be able to just merge those rows together, or in other words, take out the row that has the NA value. It's okay that all of the other values in the table are NA.

Here's my data:

```
> dput(stackoverflow[1:100,])
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1432425600, 1432426500, 1432427400, 
1432428300, 1432429200, 1432430100, 1432431000, 1432431900, 1432432800, 
1432433700, 1432434600, 1432435500, 1432436400, 1432437300, 1432438200, 
1432439100, 1432440000, 1432440900, 1432441800, 1432442700, 1432443600, 
1432444500, 1432445400, 1432446300, 1432447200, 1432448100, 1432449000, 
1432449900, 1432450800, 1432450800, 1432451700, 1432452600, 1432453500, 
1432454400, 1432454400, 1432455300, 1432456200, 1432457100, 1432458000, 
1432458000, 1432458900, 1432459800, 1432460700, 1432461600, 1432461600, 
1432462500, 1432463400, 1432464300, 1432465200, 1432465200, 1432466100, 
1432467000, 1432467900, 1432468800, 1432468800, 1432469700, 1432470600, 
1432471500, 1432472400, 1432472400, 1432473300, 1432474200, 1432475100, 
1432476000, 1432476000, 1432476900, 1432477800, 1432478700, 1432479600, 
1432479600, 1432480500, 1432481400, 1432482300, 1432483200, 1432483200, 
1432484100, 1432485000, 1432485900, 1432486800, 1432486800, 1432487700, 
1432488600, 1432489500, 1432490400, 1432490400, 1432491300, 1432492200, 
1432493100, 1432494000, 1432494000, 1432494900, 1432495800, 1432496700, 
1432497600, 1432498500, 1432499400, 1432500300, 1432501200, 1432502100, 
1432503000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    Turtle = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), levels = c("R3L1", "R3L11", "R3L12", "R3L2", "R3L4", 
    "R3L8", "R3L9", "R4L8", "R8L1", "R8L4", "R8NAT123"), class = "factor"), 
    elevation = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 282.27, NA, NA, NA, NA, 283.21, NA, NA, NA, NA, 282.14, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 281.63, NA, NA, NA, NA, 281.63, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 281.63, NA, NA, NA, NA, 282.63, NA, NA, NA, NA, 281.63, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 282.14, NA, NA, NA, NA, 281.63, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 282.14, NA, NA, NA, NA, 281.36, NA, NA, NA, NA, 282.14, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]
Here's also a picture of an example of rows I would like to merge.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the data frame (here, `df`) has the same `Time` and `Turtle` values and the `NA` values are the only ones repeating and always come after the `Elevation` value, a `dplyr` approach would be:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Time, Turtle) %>% 
  slice(1)

# or

df %>% # thanks @neilfws
  group_by(Time, Turtle) %>% 
  slice_head()
```

Which groups the `Time` and `Turtle` values and takes the first value.

Comment: `slice_head` would work too.

Answer (score 1):

with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Time, Turtle) %>%
  summarise(elevation = elevation[!is.na(elevation)][1], .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 87 × 3
# Groups:   Time [87]
   Time                Turtle elevation
   <dttm>              <fct>      <dbl>
 1 2015-05-24 00:00:00 R3L1          NA
 2 2015-05-24 00:15:00 R3L1          NA
 3 2015-05-24 00:30:00 R3L1          NA
 4 2015-05-24 00:45:00 R3L1          NA
 5 2015-05-24 01:00:00 R3L1          NA
 6 2015-05-24 01:15:00 R3L1          NA
 7 2015-05-24 01:30:00 R3L1          NA
 8 2015-05-24 01:45:00 R3L1          NA
 9 2015-05-24 02:00:00 R3L1          NA
10 2015-05-24 02:15:00 R3L1          NA
```

---

Or use `distinct`

```
df1 %>% 
   arrange(Time, Turtle, is.na(elevation)) %>%
   distinct()
```